# Add Toolbar JSQMessagesViewController

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I'm doing a small chat app with JSQMessagesViewController and Firebase. I don't know how to add toolbar in this app. I have used this tutorial : https://www.raywenderlich.com/122148/firebase-tutorial-real-time-chat.

Thank you.

Comment: By toolbar, do you mean the inputToolbar? If yes, then it should already be there when you subclass JSQMessagesViewController correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
inputToolbar.contentView.leftBarButtonItem.isHidden = true
inputToolbar.contentView.leftBarButtonItemWidth = 110
inputToolbar.contentView.leftBarButtonContainerView.addSubview(ChatToolbar)
```

// ChatToolbar is your custom view for collecting multiple UIButton buttons